# Firefox doesn't release memory allocated by Javascript even when the tab which invoked the allocation is deleted

Tags: javascript, firefox, memory-management

I am using JavaScript to allocate a large number of objects using a large amount of memory. I can't figure out how to release the memory. Even when the browser tab invoking the JavaScript is closed the memory remains unreleased.

Before invocation the about:memory report for Web Content shows 227.3MB explicit of which 32.4MB are window-objects.

While active the about:memory report for Web Content shows 2.8GB explicit of which 2.7GB are window-objects.

After tab closing the about:memory report for Web Content shows 2.8GB explicit of which 2.7GB are window-objects.

Comment: @Adam - I don't see how this is a duplicate of that.  This post is about closing a tabbed window.  That post was only about individual DOM objects within a page that was staying active.

Comment: That sounds more like a firefox than a javascript problem. And are you sure that FF doesn't release the memory when something else tries to claim it (a new tab, another process)?

Comment: Why do you need FF to release the memory? What is the problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: @C.Lamb - Oh, OK, I thought you are talking about some kind of a tab panel, not the browser tab.

Comment: @Bergi Yes, it is likely a Firefox problem. I have tried using the "free memory" tools on the "about:memory" and the Ramback add-on to coax Firefox into releasing the memory but they didn't do it. The problem I am trying to solve is running out of memory. Running that Javascript again tries to grab the same amount of memory and crashes Firefox. The only way to run it more than once is to shut down Firefox inbetween.

Comment: There is no way to release memory in JS. All you can do is not hold onto it, and to allocate in appropriate ways, and hope the garbage collector figures it out. If you have problems, you will need to show us your code (or the parts of it that are necessary to reproduce the issue).

Comment: OK, I created a simple example and learned something important. If the HTML invoking the JavaScript is read directly by FireFox the memory gets released fine. If the HTML is created by an XSL transform the memory doesn't get released.